# Doing multiple things in a React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if it's possible to manipulate multiple things in a component when a button is clicked.

At the moment I have a simple component. When the button is clicked it adds an id to an array... pretty simple stuff.

But what I want to also do when the button is pressed is change the button text to 'Selected' and add the 'color="danger"' tag to the button.

I'm finding this really difficult. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Card, CardBody, Button } from "reactstrap";

class ThisComponent extends Component {

    addResponse(id) {
        this.props.addResponseInState(id);
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props;

        return (
            <Col>
                <Card>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.addResponse(id)}>Select</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}

export default ThisComponent;
```

Comment: keep button text in state, and update state when button is clicked, for adding dynamic class you can use if based on state text or you can use ref or you can use className for dynamic class

Comment: This is pretty easy in react, add variables in state, in render use condition based on state (eg; color, text etc). Update state using `setState`. Whenever a state is updated react automagically rerender the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should get familiar with using component-state, which is the bread and butter of React.
`State` essentially helps you keep track of the component at all times, be it some sort of status or some data you want to maintain.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Card, CardBody, Button } from "reactstrap";

class ThisComponent extends Component {
    state = {
      clicked: false
    }

    addResponse(id) {
        this.props.addResponseInState(id);
        this.setState({
           clicked: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props;

        return (
            <Col>
                <Card>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Button
                          color={this.state.clicked ? "danger" : ""}
                          onClick={() => this.addResponse(id)}
                        >
                            { !this.state.clicked ? "Select" : "Selected"}
                        </Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}

export default ThisComponent;
```

Comment: Hey ... This works except for the color of the button, it doesnt change to a danger button

Comment: Hey, please try now. I made a change for color.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, the code should look like this in the end `<Button color="danger"`

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya its weird the prop should be working, but not sure why it doesnt accept the class, I'm testing it in a sandbox :o

Comment: Hey .... Thank you for your answer ... I ended up fixing it using the following; `<Button color={this.state.clicked ? "danger" : ""}` ... Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want in your function. But you should also add state to your component if you want to store some data inside.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Card, CardBody, Button } from "reactstrap";

class ThisComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            isSelected: false,
        }
    }

    addResponse(id) {
        this.props.addResponseInState(id);
        
        this.setState({isSelected: true})
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props;
        const { isSelected } = this.state;

        return (
            <Col>
                <Card>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Button 
                           onClick={() => this.addResponse(id)}
                           className={isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}
                        >
                            Select
                        </Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}

export default ThisComponent;
```